# HTML audio onplay function calling

Tags: javascript, html

I have function 'a', and i'd like to call function 'b' when the audio starts. i can call it when 'b' has no argument or the argument is a string, but it's not working when the argument is a variable.

```
function a(p){
        p.innerHTML= "<audio preload='auto' id='beep1' autoplay='true' onplay='b(p)'><source src='sounds/beep1.mp3' type='audio/mp3' /><source src='sounds/beep1.mp3' type='audio/mp3' /></audio>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `p` is not defined. You are inserting a string into HTML code. When you insert it, that variable no longer refers to the function-specific variable because it's part of the HTML, not the function. You have to define the variable separately somehow. If you post more code or a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), I can help more.